# bashscript extract info from custom row

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

under command :gpart show

```
i get the output 
=>      34  31457213  ada0  GPT  (15G)
        34       128     1  freebsd-boot  (64k)
       162  29360000     2  freebsd-ufs  (14G)
  29360162   1572864     3  freebsd-swap  (768M)
  30933026    524221        - free -  (10GB)
```

how can i extract just 14G from 3rd line and 10GB from last line?

the 14/10GB values are never the same, which makes my work harder to do.

i manage to get some results using

cat test | sed 's/\|/ /' | awk '{print $6}{print $5}'
but i still have to extract just that info,

any ideas? please thanks.

Comment: :gpart show |awk 'NR == 3 || NR == 5 { print $NF} ' |sed "s/(//;s/)//"

Comment: If you specifically want the `freebsd-ufs` partition, you should filter on that rather than hoping it will always be line 3...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F '[()]' 'NR==3 {print $(NF-1)} END{print $(NF-1)}' file.txt
```

- `-F '[()]'` sets the field delimiter as `(` or `)`
- `NR==3 {print $(NF-1)}` prints the desired field for the third line
- `END{print $(NF-1)}` prints the desired field for the last line

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
    34  31457213  ada0  GPT  (15G)
        34       128     1  freebsd-boot  (64k)
       162  29360000     2  freebsd-ufs  (14G)
  29360162   1572864     3  freebsd-swap  (768M)
  30933026    524221        - free -  (10GB)

% awk -F '[()]' 'NR==3 {print $(NF-1)} END{print $(NF-1)}' file.txt
14G
10GB
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below solution -

```
vipin@kali:~$ cat kk.txt
     34  31457213  ada0  GPT  (15G)
        34       128     1  freebsd-boot  (64k)
       162  29360000     2  freebsd-ufs  (14G)
  29360162   1572864     3  freebsd-swap  (768M)
  30933026    524221        - free -  (10GB)
   vipin@kali:~$ awk -F'\(|\)' 'NR==3 || NR==5 {print $(NF -1)}' kk.txt
14G
10GB
```

explanation -

use escape character `\` to use `()` and `|` for multiple Field seperator and `NR` to select multiple lines and `NF-1` to print last column when `()` is field seperator.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file 
      34  31457213  ada0  GPT  (15G)
        34       128     1  freebsd-boot  (64k)
       162  29360000     2  freebsd-ufs  (14G)
  29360162   1572864     3  freebsd-swap  (768M)
  30933026    524221        - free -  (10GB)
$ egrep -o '\([0-9]+\w+\)$' file | sed -n '3p;5p'
(14G)
(10GB)
```

matches regex `'\([0-9]+\w+\)$'` i.e 1 or more digits followed by 1 or more word chars, both contained in round brackets and using `sed` to print 3rd and 5th line